# Is it safe to rename files while using readdir?

Tags: perl

While scanning a directory with [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html), can you safely rename files without worrying about entering an infinite recursion? For example:

```
use v5.12;  # make readdir set $_ in while loops
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my $dir = 'tdir';    
opendir ( my $dh, $dir ) or die "Could not open dir '$dir': $!";
while (readdir $dh) {
    next if /^\.\.?\z/;
    my $filename = File::Spec->catfile( $dir, $_ );
    if ( -f $filename) {
        my $newname = File::Spec->catfile( $dir, "prefix_$_" );
        rename ($filename, $newname) or warn $!;
    }
}

closedir $dh;
```

So after renaming for example `file` to `prefix_file`, `readdir` will not find `prefix_file` in a later iteration of the `while` loop (and then rename it again to `prefix_prefix_file` and so on? Probably obvious that it will not do this, but since I could not find it mentioned in the documentation I'll ask the question anyway.

Comment: `readdir` does find recursively however it will not find by an infinite way. [refer](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Answer

The underlying system call is POSIX's [`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html), and the specification says:

> If a file is removed from or added to the directory after the most recent call to `opendir()` or `rewinddir()`, whether a subsequent call to `readdir()` returns an entry for that file is unspecified.

It simply means that you might or might not get to see the files.  You might find that a particular platform does specify what happens, but it probably isn't portable to other systems.

---

#### Demonstration

[ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015527/is-it-safe-to-rename-files-while-using-readdir/39017355?noredirect=1#comment65400149_39017355):

> `rename` neither adds nor removes any directory entries, though. It just edits one.

I responded:

> It (`rename()`) changes an entry in the directory; what happens depends on how [the file system] is implemented. If you change the file name from `a` to `humongous-long-name-that-is-too-boring-to-be-believable`, there's a decent chance that the entry will move in the directory on disk, leading to unspecified behaviour [as noted in the main answer]. … Whether … `rename()` actually screws up a scan with `readdir()` depends on the system (operating system and file system), which is all that I claimed.

After further discussion, I created this example of what can and does happen on one specific system.  I used the steps:

- Create a directory — its name does not matter.
- Change into that directory.
- Copy `readdir.c` and `make.files.sh` into the directory.
- Create program `readdir` from source `readdir.c` (use `make readdir`, for example).

  - The code assumes that the `struct dirent` includes member `d_namlen` which is not mandated by POSIX.
  - It would be feasible to do without it (but minor changes would be needed).
- Create a file (or directory) `a`.
- Run `./readdir`.  Hit return when it prompts you.  You should see
  output similar to this, but the inode numbers will be different.

```
    $ ./readdir
    44249044: (  1) .
    42588881: (  2) ..
    44260959: ( 10) .gitignore
    44398380: (  1) a
    Found entry 'a' - hit return to continue: 
    Continuing...
    44398371: ( 10) make.files
    44398280: ( 13) make.files.sh
    44398338: (  8) makefile
    44398351: (  7) readdir
    44260963: (  9) readdir.c
    44398352: ( 12) readdir.dSYM
    44260960: (  9) README.md
    44398364: (  6) rename
    44260964: (  8) rename.c
    44398365: ( 11) rename.dSYM
    $
```

- Run `sh make.files.sh`.  This will create files `moderately-long-file-name.000` .. `moderately-long-file-name.999`.
- Run `./readdir` again. Do not hit return yet.
- Switch to a different terminal window.
- Change directory to the one where the test is being run.
- Run: `mv a  zzz-let-sleeping-file-renames-lie-unperturbed`
- Switch back to the terminal window running `readdir`.
- Hit return.  You will probably see output similar to:

```
    $ ./readdir
    44249044: (  1) .
    42588881: (  2) ..
    44260959: ( 10) .gitignore
    44398380: (  1) a
    Found entry 'a' - hit return to continue: 
    Continuing...
    44398371: ( 10) make.files
    44398280: ( 13) make.files.sh
    44398338: (  8) makefile
    44431473: ( 29) moderately-long-file-name.000
    44431474: ( 29) moderately-long-file-name.001
    44431475: ( 29) moderately-long-file-name.002
    ...
    44432470: ( 29) moderately-long-file-name.997
    44432471: ( 29) moderately-long-file-name.998
    44432472: ( 29) moderately-long-file-name.999
    44398351: (  7) readdir
    44260963: (  9) readdir.c
    44398352: ( 12) readdir.dSYM
    44260960: (  9) README.md
    44398364: (  6) rename
    44260964: (  8) rename.c
    44398365: ( 11) rename.dSYM
    44398380: ( 45) zzz-let-sleeping-file-renames-lie-unperturbed
    $
```

This is what I got on Mac OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan with the default HFS+
file system.  When the directory was small (without the moderately long
file names), then the renamed file did not show up.  When the extra
files were created so that the directory size was around 34 KiB, then
the renamed file did show up.

This demonstrates that on some file systems (specifically, Apple's HFS+)
and under some circumstances, the `readdir()` scan of a directory is
affected by a rename operation on a file.  If you wish to write and use
a `rename` command instead of using `mv`, so be it — when I tried,
it made no difference to the result.

## Conclusion

On other file systems or other operating systems, YMMV.  However, this
suffices to demonstrate that on some systems, renaming a file while a
`readdir()` scan is in progress can end up with the same 'file' appearing
twice in the output.

#### `make.files.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for file in $(seq -f 'moderately-long-file-name.%03.0f' 0 999)
do > "$file"
done
```

#### `readdir.c`

```c
/* SO 3901-5527 - attempt to demonstrate renaming moving entries */
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const char *stop_after = "a";

static void process_directory(const char *dirname)
{
    DIR *dp = opendir(dirname);

    if (dp == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open directory %s\n", dirname);
    else
    {
        struct dirent *entry;
        while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != 0)
        {
            /* Ignore current and parent directory */
            printf("%8d: (%3d) %s\n", (int)entry->d_ino, entry->d_namlen, entry->d_name);
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, stop_after) == 0)
            {
                printf("Found entry '%s' - hit return to continue: ", stop_after);
                fflush(stdout);
                char *buffer = 0;
                size_t buflen = 0;
                getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin);
                free(buffer);
                printf("Continuing...\n");
            }
        }
        closedir(dp);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 's':
            stop_after = optarg;
            break;;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unrecognized option '-%c'\n", argv[0], optopt);
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-s stop_after] [directory ...]\n", argv[0]);
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    if (optind == argc)
        process_directory(".");
    else
    {
        for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
            process_directory(argv[i]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is first to `chdir` into your directory so that there is no issue with building paths, and then use `glob` in list context, which will return all the names in one go without any chance of confusion

It would look like this (untested)

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie qw/ chdir rename /;

chdir 'tdir';

rename $_, "prefix_$_" for grep -f, glob '*';
```