# How to rename the directory structure by matching the text file using perl?

Tags: perl

---

I have the following text file in which it has directory names .Now i should rename the directory names by matching the directory names with the text file using perl.

sample.txt:

```
PROJ:DEMO
PROJ:PROJECT_SPACE
PROJ:project:prj1
BLOCK:block:blk1
CHECKLIST:design_check:checklist1
```

original directory structure

```
├── prj1
│   ├── blk1
│   │   └── checklist1
│   │       ├── rev
│   │       │   └── rev.config
│   │       └── temp_rest
│   │           └── rev.config
│   └── block_status.config
```

Expected output directory structure:

```
├── project
│   ├── block
│   │   └── design_check
│   │       ├── rev
│   │       │   └── rev.config
│   │       └── temp_rest
│   │           └── rev.config
│   └── block_status.config
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
@filename;
$i = 0;
$total;
open(INFILE,"sample.txt");
while($filename[$i] = <INFILE>){
  chop($filename[$i]);
  $filename[$i] =~ s/\*//g;
  $i++;
  $total++;
}
```

Code Explanation:

I tried to read the text file and used substitution and used increment operator to include the files.

I had struck with further things to add to make the expected directory structure.

Comment: unix user, right? if so, you can find all directories using `find -type d` and `rename` them, if the dir name is at your list

Comment: See also [Is it safe to rename files while using readdir?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39015527/2173773)

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have the time to put in it, but in general: `@dirs = \`find . -type d\``, open your file and take the from, to you need `if (/.*\:(.*):(.*)/) {...`, replace the first occurance of $2 to $1 and `map` the rest of the @dirs from $2 to $1

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Please don't post code that we can't run. Did you just add `use strict` to avoid being told off when you posted your code here? Even with out `use strict` you get two `Useless use of a variable in void context` warnings.

Comment: Where is `prj1`? Is it a root directory?

Comment: prj1 is not root directory(the actual directory path will be /home/data/DEMO/PROJECT_SPACE/prj1/blk1/checklist1/rev/rev.config @ Borodin

Comment: I'm curious... what does the decision tree look like for creating a new account vs. using one of your many [existing](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7608729/find-data) [accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7341243/example-file)? Is there a rhyme and reason to it, or is it completely random?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, but be careful and take a backup before you experiment with this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd qw(getcwd);
use File::Copy ();

my $dir_map = read_map( 'sample.txt' );
my $top_dir = '.';

rename_dirs( $top_dir, $dir_map );

 sub rename_dirs {
    my ( $top_dir, $dir_map ) = @_;

    opendir (my $dh, $top_dir) or die "Can't open $top_dir: $!";
    my $save_dir = getcwd();
    chdir $top_dir;
    while (my $dir = readdir $dh) {
        next if ($dir eq '.') or ($dir eq '..'); 
        if ( exists $dir_map->{$dir} ) {
            my $new_name = $dir_map->{$dir};
            #say "$save_dir: rename $dir $new_name";
            File::Copy::move( $dir, $new_name )
                or die "Could not rename '$dir' as '$new_name': $!";
            $dir = $new_name;
        }
        rename_dirs( $dir, $dir_map ) if -d $dir;
    }
    chdir $save_dir;
}

sub read_map {
    my ( $fn ) = @_;

    my %dir_map;

    open( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        my @fields = split /:/, $line;
        if ( @fields == 3 ) {
            $dir_map{$fields[2]} = $fields[1];
        }
    }
    close $fh;
    return \%dir_map;
}
```