# How to rename files with its linking directory names using perl?

Tags: perl

---

I like to rename my files with directory names using perl.I included my directory structure as follows:

```
    |-- Basket
    |   |-- ICC
    |   |   |-- rest10-rest10-rest10-test.txt
    |   |   `-- rest1
    |   |       `-- rest1-rest1-rest1-rest.txt
    |   |-- bl2-bl2-bl2-b1.txt
```

Expected :

```
    |-- Basket
    |   |-- ICC
    |   |   |-- ICC_rest10.txt
    |   |   `-- rest1
    |   |       `-- ICC_rest1.txt
    |   |-- Basket_bl2.txt
```

My code:(i tried by taking all .txt files)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $dir = '/home/user1/output';
my @files = glob "${dir}*.txt*";
foreach (@files) {
    next if -d;
    my $o_name = $_;
    rename $o_name, $_  or
        $_ = $o_name,
        print $_;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You don't make any changes to `$o_name`, so your `rename` won't change the name of the files. You are also looking in only a single directory so your subdirectories won't get processed.

Comment: duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527874/how-to-rename-the-directory-structure-by-matching-the-text-file-using-perl

Comment: i think there they are changing the directory names by matching with some file.Here i like to change the text file with directory names inside the respective directories.Then how it will be duplicate of that question@user2141046

Comment: My question is to rename the .txt files with respected directory names.@Borodin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
sub runDir($$);
sub runDir($$) {
    my $prefix = shift @_;
    my $dir = shift @_;
    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
    my @entries = readdir(DIR);
    close(DIR);
    foreach my $file (@entries) {
        next if ($file =~ /^\.+$/);
        if ( -d $dir . '/' . $file) {
            runDir($prefix . $file . '_', $dir . '/' . $file);
        } elsif ( ( -f $dir . '/' . $file ) && ( $file =~ /\.txt$/ ) ) {
            my $suffix = $file;
            $suffix =~ s/^(\S+)-.+\.txt$/$1.txt/;
            print "rename $dir . '/' . $file, $dir . '/' . $prefix . $suffix . \n";
        }
    }
}
runDir('output_', '/home/user1/output');
```

But beware of filename collisions:

```
rest1-rest1-rest.txt
rest1-rest1-rest1-rest.txt
```

in same dir...

Comment: i have few queries 1)why you had used($$) 2) if i execute this code it names the directory if i again execute the same code it renames the file names twice why it happens like that..for example(rest1-rest1-rest_rest1-rest1-rest.txt) @ v.sheldeshov

Comment: ($$) - it was just to define that runDir wants strictly 2 variables. To avoid errors when use it later. "res-res" problem: well it is not too hard to add additional check if filename starts from prefix. Replace } elsif ( ( -f $dir . '/' . $file ) && ( $file =~ /\.txt$/ ) ) {     ...................... with } elsif ( ( -f $dir . '/' . $file ) && ( $file =~ /\.txt$/ ) && ( $file !~ /^$prefix/ ) ) {