# How can Perl verify that a path is a directory yet not be able to call opendir() on the very same?

Tags: perl, find

I'm trying to find empty subdirectories and delete them. I'm sure there are better ways to achieve this (I'm a poor programmer and relatively new with Perl) but even so, I'd like to understand what's wrong with my approach.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename; 
use File::Find

my $lambda2 = sub
{
    my $path = $File::Find::name;
    if ( -d $path )
    {
        print("Directory: ", $path, "\n");

        # Define anonymous function to test if directory is empty
        my $hasContent = sub
        {
            my $directory = shift;
            opendir ( my $dh, $directory );
            return scalar ( grep { $_ ne "." && $_ ne ".." } readdir ( $dh ) );
        };
        # Remove item if it is an empty directory
        if ( ! $hasContent->( $path ) )
        {
            rmdir( $path );
        }
    }
};
my $directory = "/Users/username/testdir/";

find( { wanted => $lambda2, no_chdir => 1 }, $directory );
```

If testdir has an empty subdirectory called testsubdir, say, I get the seemingly contradictory response:

```
Directory: /Users/username/testdir
Directory: /Users/username/testdir/testsubdir
Can't opendir(/Users/username/testdir/testsubdir): No such file or directory
```

The printing of the latter directory implies that it passed the -d check, but the subsequent error message says there is no such directory. As far as I can see nothing occurs inbetween.

Comment: Have you checked permissions? Your code doesn't print out an error message when opendir fails, so it'd likely be helpful to have exactly the code that produces the exact error message.

Comment: are you open to other not perl solutions? with find and du.

Comment: See also [Is it safe to rename files while using readdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39015527/2173773)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code's removing directories under `find`'s feet, so to speak.

The simplest fix: change `find` to `finddepth`, for [postorder traversal](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html#DESCRIPTION), since

> it invokes the `&wanted` function for a directory *after* invoking it for the directory's contents.

(original emphasis)   Then it won't attempt to invoke `wanted` on the directory just removed.

Or, merely collect the list of empty directories in `find` and delete them after `find` completes.

Answer (score 4):

Let's throw in some logging statements and see what is happening:

```
my $lambda2 = sub {
    my $path = $File::Find::name;
    if ( -d $path ) {
        print("Directory: ", $path, "\n");
        my $hasContent = sub {
            my $directory = shift;
            opendir ( my $dh, $directory );
            return scalar ( grep { $_ ne "." && $_ ne ".." } readdir ( $dh ) );
        };
        my $hc = $hasContent->($path);
        print STDERR "hc($path) = $hc\n";
        if (! $hc) {
            print STDERR "Deleting $path\n";
            rmdir( $path );
        }
    }
};

$ mkdir -p /Users/username/testdir/testsubdir
$ perl subdir.pl
Directory: /Users/username/testdir
hc(/Users/username/testdir) = 1
Directory: /Users/username/testdir/testsubdir
hc(/Users/username/testdir/testsubdir) = 0
Deleting /Users/username/testdir/testsubdir
Can't opendir(/Users/username/testdir/testsubdir): No such file or directory
 at subdir.pl line 26.
```

So the code is more or less working as designed, it's just that `File::Find` is trying to walk `/Users/username/testdir/testsubdir` after you have deleted it.

Comment: I can't see how opendir is ever called on testsubdir a second time, after it has been deleted. Or are you saying that the opendir error message isn't from my code from the internals of File::Find?

Comment: @JamesMachin  It's indeed from the "internals" (as `wanted` is invoked), as it attempts to go through the list of items (while a subdir has just been processed and removed).

Comment: @zdim Right I see, thank you for that clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Using `du` and `awk`.

List all empty directories under `$target_directory`

```
 du $target_directory| awk '$1=="0"{print $2}'
```

Remove all empty directories under `$target_directory`

```
 du $target_directory| awk '$1=="0"{system("rmdir "$2);}'
```