# What order does Perl use by default to read all files in a directory?

Tags: perl

I have .gz files inside a directory and I am reading them with Perl. Everything is ok but what I don't understand is the order in which this files are being read. For sure, I can tell that it is not alphabetical. So my question is what order does Perl use by default to read files from a directory.

Below is a snippet of my code

```
# Open the source file  
my $dir = "/home/myname/mydir";

# Open directory and loop through
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    # We only want files
    next unless (-f "$dir/$file");

    # Use a regular expression to find files ending in .gz
    next unless ($file =~ m/\.gz$/);

    my $gzip_file = "./mydir/$file";

    open ( my $gunzip_stream, "-|", "gzip -dc $gzip_file") or die $!;
    while (my $line = <$gunzip_stream> ) {
        print ("$line\n");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you can use [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html) to read those files directly from perl without having to launch another process.

Comment: `readdir` returns the files in the same order as the system returns them

Comment: You can also use [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/functions/glob.html) instead of `opendir`/`readdir`: `my @files = glob "home/myname/mydir/*.gz";`

Comment: Tip: `/\.gz$/` should be `/\.gz\z/` if you want to match file names ending in `.gz`

Comment: @ikegami kindly explain your tip. Why should I use `/\.gz\z/` instead of what I am using because at the moment everything seems to working fine. What are the pitfalls?

Comment: @Phemelo Khetho, It doesn't match just files ending with `.gz`. It also matches those that end with `.gz␊`

Comment: Tip: `"gzip -dc $gzip_file"` should be`use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote ); shell_quote("gzip", "-dc", "--", $gzip_file")` to handle file names that contain shell meta characters (e.g. spaces, `?`, `*`, `(`, `)`, etc) and those that start with `-`. (Ok, so a file name starting with `-` is not actually possible here, but might as well get into the habit of using `--` for when it does and to future-proof your code.)

Comment: Actually, `shell_quote` isn't needed. Using `open ( my $gunzip_stream, "-|", "gzip", "-dc", "--", $gzip_file)` would also address the issues.

Comment: See also [Is it safe to rename files while using readdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39015527/2173773)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readdir` returns the files in the same order as the system returns them. I'm not aware of any guarantee of order from any OS. I imagine different drives might even behave differently.