# Improve regex to rename files

Tags: regex, ubuntu

I need help to improve the perfomance of a custom function used to rename files recursively in a directory. This is how the functions look like:

```
# Rename the files to Kebab Case recursively
# @param {string} $d directory name
renameToKebab() {
    d="${1:-$(pwd)}"
    # replace whitespaces and underscores with hyphens
    find $d -execdir rename 's/[ _]/-/g' '{}' \+
    # put a hyphen between words that are in Camel/Pascal case
    find $d -execdir rename 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/$1-$2/g' '{}' \+
    # replace two or more hyphens with a single hyphen
    find $d -execdir rename 's/-+/-/g' '{}' \+
    # replace -( with (
    find $d -execdir rename 's/\(-/(/g' '{}' \+
    # replace )- with )
    find $d -execdir rename 's/-\)/)/g' '{}' \+
    # transform upper case letters into lower case
    find $d -execdir rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' '{}' \+
}

# Rename the files to underscore case recursively
# @param {string} $d directory name
renameToUnderscore() {
    d="${1:-$(pwd)}"
    find $d -execdir rename 's/[ -]/_/g' '{}' \+
    find $d -execdir rename 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/$1_$2/g' '{}' \+
    find $d -execdir rename 's/_+/_/g' '{}' \+
    find $d -execdir rename 's/\(_/(/g' '{}' \+
    find $d -execdir rename 's/_\)/)/g' '{}' \+
    find $d -execdir rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' '{}' \+
}
```

This function is written in `bash` and is located in `~/.bash_profile`. The `rename` command is a terminal tool that renames files using `Perl` regex. I'm **not** familiar with `Perl`.

The problem of the script above is that it executes the `rename` command six times. So, every time I run these functions it takes some seconds to rename the files. I'd like to optimize the regex so I need to execute `rename` only once/twice. That would make things much faster.

Thanks in advance.

**Note**
rename version: 0.20
OS: Ubuntu 18

Comment: Take a look to `detox` project

Comment: @GillesQuenot can you provide a url to this project? The first thing I found when searching for 'detox project' was this https://detoxproject.org/, which is about food. I suppose you are not talking this site since it is about food

Comment: https://github.com/dharple/detox (exists as debian/ubuntu package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do all the processing in Perl eliminating the need to call the external commands `find` and `rename` multiple times. I am only showing the first function `renameToKebab()`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd qw(getcwd);
use File::Find;

sub rename_to_kebab {
    my $d = shift || getcwd();
    find(\&rename_to_kebab_helper, $d);
}

sub rename_to_kebab_helper {
    my $orig_name = $_;

    return if ($_ eq ".") || ($_ eq ".."); 
    # replace whitespaces and underscores with hyphens
    s/[ _]/-/g;
    # put a hyphen between words that are in Camel/Pascal case
    s/([a-z])([A-Z])/$1-$2/g;
    # replace two or more hyphens with a single hyphen
    s/-+/-/g;
    # replace -( with (
    s/\(-/(/g;
    # replace )- with )
    s/-\)/)/g;
    # transform upper case letters into lower case
    y/A-Z/a-z/;
    return if $_ eq $orig_name;
    if ( -e $_ ) {
        say "File '$_' exists in directory: ", $File::Find::dir;
        say "   -> skipping";
        return;
    }
    my $success = rename $orig_name, $_;
    if ( !$success ) {
        say "Could not rename '$orig_name' to '$_': $!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Add an actual call to `rename_to_kebab()` (with suitable arguments) ?

Comment: @zdim Yes you need to call it of course, I left that as an exercise for the OP.. StudentofScience : let me know if you need more details

Comment: Thank you !! But how do I use it? I mean, I currently have `renameToKebab` in `.bash_profile`, so it is automatically loaded when I open a terminal. What I can do to automatially load the perl file? Moreover, will the function written in `Perl` be executed from a bash shell?

Comment: @StudentofScience You are welcome. You can change the `PATH` environment variable for Bash so it will find the Perl script, or you can put the Perl script in a directory that is already in `PATH`

Comment: @StudentofScience To use the script you have to modify it slightly such that it accepts a command line argument (the directory to start from) and then calls `rename_to_kebab()` with that argument

Comment: I have another doubt, in which part of the code are you using the regex to chane `$_`? In the helper function, between the two `return if`, we have `s/[ _]/-/g;`,  `s/-+/-/g;`, etc. I don't see the variable `$_` here. How are you changing it?

Comment: @StudentofScience Good question. It is supplied by the `Find::File` module, see [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find#The-wanted-function)

Comment: See also [Is it safe to rename files while using readdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39015527/2173773). It might be necessary to do the renaming of the files after all the files in a directory have been found

Comment: Thanks! That clarified things. So, I put the code in `~/rename.t`, but when I tried to load it using `. ~/rename.t` I got the errors `line 3: syntax error near unexpected token ('`   and  `line 3: use feature qw(say);`

Comment: @StudentofScience Let us continue the discussion on email if it is ok with you? You can find my email in my profile.