# Rename File with perl

Tags: perl

I want to rename files with Perl. `Example_22VOO0142321.xml` ⇒ `22VOO0142321.xml`
the numbers are different but example_ has to leave. How can I remove example_ from the filenames?

```
opendir( D, "$source_dir" ) or mail_die("Fout bij openen van $source_dir : $!");

my @allfiles = grep { -f "$source_dir/$_" } readdir D;

closedir D;

my @examplefiles = grep { /example_.+(\.xml)$/i } @allfiles;  

my $file_name;
foreach $file_name (@examplefiles) {
   ??
}
```

Comment: In `foreach` loop you can use `move()` function of `File::Copy` to get this work.

Comment: See also [Is it safe to rename files while using readdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39015527/2173773)

Comment: @Håkon Hægland Relevant for `while readdir` (renaming while reading), but not for `for readdir` (renaming after doing all the reading)

Comment: @ikegami Good point!

Comment: Tip: `my $x; for $x ( ... )` should be written `for my $x ( ... )`

Comment: If you in Linux then you  could utilize utility [rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html). A few other sample of [renaming](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-rename-files-in-linux/) files.

Answer (score 1):

You would almost certainly be better off using File::Copy (the word "almost" here being merely a hedge, you really don't want to do this with low level functions), but you could do something like:

```
use 5.12.0;

my $path = shift;
opendir my $dir, $path or die "can't opendir $path: $!";

for my $name ( grep { /^example_/ && -f "$path/$_" } readdir($dir) ){
        rename("$path/$name", "$path/" . substr $name, 8) or die "$name: $!";
}
```

But, to reiterate, you really don't want to do this.  Use File::Copy instead.  From `perldoc rename`:  "Behavior of this function varies wildly depending on your system implementation."   Don't use it.

Comment: Re "*You would almost certainly be better off using File::Copy*", Not at all. `rename`'s limitation is that it can't rename files across volumes. No need to use `move` when the file isn't changing directory.

Comment: `rename` will also fail if the destination file already exists. (Probably a good thing here.) I don't know if `move` does the same.

Comment: @ikegami `File::Copy.copy` would certainly be a bad choice, but `File::Copy.move` would be more robust.

Comment: ???? I didn't mention `copy`. I specifically said there's no need to use `move` here, and I explained that using it might even be *worse* than using `rename` here.

Comment: @ikegami Apologies for misreading.  How would `move` be worse?  It's potentially more difficult to use, but it provides more robust error handling and consistency across different platforms.

Comment: See second comment.

Comment: `move` isn't hard to use. Quite the opposite. /// `move` doesn't provide more robust error handling. (If anything, it's the opposite. But not by much.) /// No idea what kind of inconsistency across platforms to which you refer, and how you think `move` addresses them.

Comment: ok, I stand corrected on platforms. When resolving relative dst paths, VMS's `rename` apparently uses the src path as the base path rather than the CWD.  `move` behaves like on unix and Windows even on VMS. So I guess there's a benefit if you care about VMS.

Comment: File::Copy has many other issues with preserving metadata and other edge cases that people find surprising.